Can you trigger Power Automate Flow using just Application ID ie App Registration in Azure and not an actual user?
I have an Azure App Registration and trying to trigger Power Automate Flow using that application id. Do I need an actual user like a service principal type user or can I do it just by using application id ie app registration in azure? The Flow is set to any user within tenant can trigger which makes me think app id is not compatible here.
